# Tomcat application not responding after a certain period

Tags: tomcat

I have a scenario wherein my application deployed on Tomcat is working perfectly well, but stops responding after about a week.

I am not able to understand what the issue could be, though my guess is that it is related to some memory issue.

Has anyone else faced this issue, and what is a possible resolution to such an issue.

Thanks,

chet

Answer (score 1):

Take a thread dump to see what the threads of your application are doing.

under your %JDK_Home%/bin folder there is a program jvisualvm.exe (or .sh on linux)
connect it to your running application and choose the thread tab and click the Thread Dump button. this will show you if you have stuck threads. Once your server runs out of threads than it will stop responding to requests.

If it is a memory issue like you first thought, then in your %tomcat%/logs folder you will see exceptions in the logs saying there is memory exceptions.